# How to exclude DVI files from the target list of latexmk?

Tags: latexmk

I use upLaTeX, which cannot produce PDF directly, for Japanese document and `latexmk` for the automation of typesetting sequence. My typical `.latexmkrc` for upLaTeX is like this (extraction of relevant parts):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$pdf_mode = 3;
$latex = 'uplatex -file-line-error -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S';
$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S';
```

Now, I want `latexmk` to delete DVI automatically because I don't need it. I tried a new configuration regarding `$dvipdf`.

```
$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S && rm %B.dvi';
```

This works almost well, but one problem has emerged. Although I intentionally deleted DVI, `latexmk` says it failed to make a DVI file.

```
$ latexmk test.tex
# other logs here
Running 'dvipdfmx  -o "test.pdf" "test.dvi" && rm "test".dvi'
------------
test.dvi -> test.pdf
[1]
6802 bytes written
Failure to make 'test.dvi'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
```

When `latexmk` yields no error with the first `.latexmkrc`, it says `Latexmk: All targets (test.pdf test.dvi) are up-to-date`. So I guess the existence of `test.dvi` is necessary for `latexmk` to successfully finish.

How can I exclude DVI from the target list so that `latexmk` can succeed in this situation?

One alternative is to use `$pdf_update_method` and `$pdf_update_command`:

```
$pdf_update_method = 4;
$pdf_update_command = 'rm %R.dvi';
```

However, this requires `-pvc` option, which is undesirable to me.

Comment: why don't you just remove the `.dvi` after the compile?

Comment: @naphaneal because I just don't want to do it manually while using automation tool.

Comment: create a make file that removes the `.dvi` after compiling the `.pdf`.

Comment: @naphaneal If I use Make, I need to prepare a makefile for each document. On the other hand, `$HOME/.latexmkrc` is sufficient for the global setting of `latexmk`, and that's why I want to use `latexmk` instead of Make or its friends like OMake.

Comment: actually, you don't. if you create an all-purpose-makefile for your `LaTeX`-projects, you are able to reuse it. anyway: the man-pages of latexmk indicate, it is possible to turn off the creation of `.dvi` files using the switch `-dvi-`. does this help?

Comment: @naphaneal you're right, but what I meant by prepare is that I have to place that Makefile in each directory, _not_ that I have to write from scratch every time I make new materials. I tried using `-dvi-` option, but unfortunately it was invalid in this case (seems to be overridden as the documentation says).